# firefox - install an extension "silently"

Tags: firefox, cmd, firefox-addon, installation

Our company has an application for windows and we would like to expand it for browsers.

Is it possible to install an extension in firefox from c# code?
If possible, is it possible to install it silently (install and enable silently)?

I noticed that antivirus applications do it - so there gotta be a way.

Bests for all!

Comment: Are you performing this operation as the user or as an administrator?

Comment: @Makyen as user

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this thread](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1091860) it is apparently possible.

You can [Add an extension using the windows registry](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Adding_extensions_using_the_Windows_registry)